# Double Summation: Help needed with proof

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, summation

This question is about Theorem 8.3 of Baby Rudin:

> [image]
>   [image]

what I don't understand is:

1. What is $E$? Is it subset of any metric space? Also, I can't see how $f_i$ continuous at $x_0$, because we are talking about only one sequence of set, converging to $x_0$.
2. I have been struggling since yesterday to figure out why $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_{ij}$$ is permissible, and why $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_{ij}$ indeed converges.

Comment: $E$ is any generic countable set with those points.

Comment: I am writing an answer. Request you to wait.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

$E$ is an abstract topological space. That is, as a set $E = \{x_0,x_1,x_2,...\}$, and the topology on $E$ is such that $x_n \to x_0$ in the topology of $E$. In other words, the open sets of the topology on $E$ ensure that $x_i, i>0$ are discrete points of $E$, and that $x_0$ is the only limit point.

A way of *realizing* $E$, is to look at it as a subset of another topological space, for example $E = \{0\} \cup \{\frac 1n : n \in \mathbb N\}$ as a subset of $\mathbb R$ qualifies. What are the open sets of $E$ as a topological space? By definition of the subspace topology, any open set of $E$ is an open set of $\mathbb R$ intersected with $E$. This gives you a description of a basis of open sets on $E$ : each $\{x_i\}$ is an open set in $E$ for $i > 0$, and each $\{0\} \cup \{\frac 1n : n \geq k\}$ is an open set around zero.

Something similar occurs in the general case. More precisely, $E$ is  a first countable space, because every point has a countable local base. In  this case, it is known that continuity and *sequential continuity* are one and the same i.e. if we want to show that a function is continuous on $E$, then we don't need to look  at open sets : it will be enough to show that if $y_n \to y$ in $E$, then $f(y_n) \to f(y)$ . This will not be true if $E$ were not first countable. (Since $\mathbb R$ is first countable, this amounts to what is referred to as the "sequential definition of continuity" on the real line).

However, in $E$ there is only one non-trivial example of a convergent sequence (the rest are all constant sequences or a modification/subsequence of this sequence), namely $x_n \to x_0$. So, it will be enough to show $f(x_n) \to f(x_0)$ for continuity of $f$ on $E$.

$f_i,g$  are functions defined on $E$. To show that they are continuous on $E$, we only need to show the sequential definition of convergence, as I mentioned earlier.

So why is $f_i$ continuous? We need to check that $f_i(x_n) \to f_i(x_0)$, or that $\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij} \to \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} a_{ij}$. However, the series $\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_{ij}$ is *absolutely convergent*, this is what $(12)$ is saying. Recall that this means that $\sum_{j=n+1}^\infty |a_{ij}| \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. However, by the triangle inequality , $\left|\sum_{j=n+1}^\infty a_{ij}\right| \leq \sum_{j=n+1}^\infty |a_{ij}|$, so if the right hand side is going to zero as $n \to \infty$, so must the left side. Deduce from this that $f_i(x_n) \to f_i(x_0)$.

$g$ is a uniformly convergent sum of continuous functions, hence continuous (refer to the theorem given in Rudin's explanation).

---

In  the sequence of equalities at the end, it seems everything is following from the definitions of $f_i,g$ and their continuity, except for the following statement :
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^\infty \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij} =\color{red}{ \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^\infty a_{ij}}
$$

the contentious part being that the right hand side does not exist a priori. Indeed, what Rudin assumes trivial, the switching of an infinite  and a finite  summation, requires some work.

Suppose we show that for each $n$,  we have $\sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^\infty a_{ij} = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}$, then the statement above would obviously follow. We know the right hand side is equal to $g(x_n)$. We have to show  the left hand side is equal to $g(x_n)$.

This follows from the fact that $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_{iJ} = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \left(\sum_{j=1}^J a_{ij} - \sum_{j=1}^{J-1} a_{ij}\right) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \sum_{j=1}^J a_{ij} - \sum_{i=1}^\infty \sum_{j=1}^{J-1} a_{ij} = g(x_{J}) - g(x_{J-1})$$

(and equal to $g(x_1)$ if $J=1$). Therefore,  the left hand side is:
$$
\sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^\infty a_{ij} = g(x_1) + \sum_{j=2}^n (g(x_j) - g(x_{j-1})) = g(x_n)
$$

Of course, since $\lim_{n \to \infty} g(x_n)$ exists and equals $g(x_0)$, the question about the limit existing is also answered. Finally, the proof is completed.

Comment: I have not enough words to appreciate this beautiful explanation! I am so thankful for clarifying so many things for me. I hope I could uvote this more than once.

Comment: You are welcome! I thought elaboration of the first part would be helpful. This is why Rudin is so much fun : in the middle of analysis you have topology coming in, he makes mathematics look like one big family.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг First, wonderful answer! Now, the line below "This follows from the fact that" is not true for J = 1, only for J >= 2.

Comment: @Caslu Thank you for the compliment! Also, I separated $J=1$ so that the term $g(x_1)$ comes. For $J \geq 2$ we get $g(x_j) - g(x_{j-1})$ , and now we get cancellations leading to $g(x_n)$ in the end. The $J=1$ case follows very similarly to the $J \geq 2$ case, because $a_{i1}$ summed over $i$ is just $g(x_1)$ by definition, right?

Answer (score 2):

> (Convergence of $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}a_{ij}$ **(I)**)
> Since $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} a_{ij} = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}f_i(x_0)$ by definition, and having supposed that $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}|a_{ij}| = b_i \quad \forall i\in E$ (where *E* is our countable set), it is clear that $f_i(x_0) \leq  b_i$. Thus, $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}a_{ij} \leq \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}b_i$. By assumption, $\sum b_i$ converges. Thus, (I) converges.
>
> (Convergence of $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_{ij}$ **(II)**): Note that $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_{ij} = \lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{j=1}^{n} \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_{ij} = \lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{ij}$.
> Since $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{ij} \leq \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}b_i$, it is clear that (II) converges as well.

Since $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}a_{ij} = f_i(x_0)$, it can be seen that $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_{ij} = \lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{ij} = \lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}f_i(x_n) = \lim_{n \to \infty} g(x_n) = g(x_0)$. By definition, $g(x_0) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}f_i(x_0)$. From (I), we know that $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}f_i(x_0) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}a_{ij}$.

Therefore, $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}a_{ij} = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_{ij}$