# Interchanging Sums

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'm looking to prove that if $a_{ij} \geq 0$ then

$$ \sum_{i=1}^\infty \sum_{j=1}^\infty a_{ij} = \sum_{j=1}^\infty \sum_{i=1}^\infty a_{ij}$$.

For my proof I let $S= \sum_{j=1}^\infty \sum_{i=1}^\infty a_{ij}$ and I establish the inequality $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \sum_{j=1}^\infty a_{ij} \leq S$.

I'm trying to prove the reverse inequality in the case that $S$ is infinite. i.e., 
$$ S \leq \sum_{i=1}^\infty \sum_{j=1}^\infty a_{ij}$$
which means that the double sum $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \sum_{j=1}^\infty a_{ij}$ is also infinite. Any ideas how to show this? I'm stumped.

Answer (score 2):

Let $b_{ij}:=a_{ji}$ and apply your first result to $b_{ij}$. Then you get the reverse result.

Comment: How? Applying the first inequality to $b_{ij}$ gives
$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \sum_{j=1}^\infty b_{ij} \leq \sum_{j=1}^\infty \sum_{i=1}^\infty b_{ij}$, but then this means
$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \sum_{j=1}^\infty a_{ji} \leq \sum_{j=1}^\infty \sum_{i=1}^\infty a_{ji}$
which is not what I want. Swapping the order of the indices doesn't swap the order of the sums.

Comment: Related:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3079002/double-summation-help-needed-with-proof?r=SearchResults

Comment: That doesn't appear to answer my specific question. Basicall I want to show if the RHS sum diverges to infinity, then so does LHS. The hypothesis include the convergence of the sums.

Comment: Note that $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}a_{ji}=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_{ij}$ and $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_{ji}=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}a_{ij}$ by swapping the names of the indices i and j. This leads to the conclusion you want.

Answer (score 1):

Note that since $a_{ij} \geqslant 0$,

$$S' = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \sum_{j=1}^\infty a_{ij} \geqslant \sum_{i=1}^\infty \sum_{j=1}^N a_{ij} = \sum_{j=1}^N \sum_{i=1}^\infty a_{ij}, $$

where the last equality follows because $\sum_{j=1}^N \lim_{M \to \infty} S_M = \lim_{M \to \infty} \sum_{j=1}^N S_M$.

(The limit of a finite sum of sequences equals the sum of the individual limits, and this is true if we have **extended** nonnegative real-valued limits).

Thus,

$$S' \geqslant \limsup_{N \to \infty} \sum_{j=1}^N \sum_{i=1}^\infty a_{ij} = S=+\infty$$

Answer (score 1):

Do not bother about convergence at all. We have $ \sum\limits_{i=1}^{N} \sum\limits_{j=1}^{M} a_{ij} =\sum\limits_{j=1}^{M} \sum\limits_{i=1}^{N} a_{ij} \leq \sum\limits_{j=1}^{\infty} \sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} a_{ij}$.  Let $M \to \infty$ and then $N \to \infty $ to get $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} \sum\limits_{j=1}^{\infty} a_{ij} \leq \sum\limits_{j=1}^{\infty} \sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} a_{ij}$. By symmtery the reverse inequality also holds.